# Copy partitioned ORC data files to another external partitioned ORC table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, orc

> Issue : incorrect row count after copying partitioned folders with ORC
>   files into another external partitioned ORC table

I have this employee table in dev schema . This table is a external partitioned ORC table.

**CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dev.employee(
  empid string,
  empname string,
  update_gmt_ts timestamp)
  PARTITIONED BY (
  partition_upd_gmt_ts string)
  stored as orc
  location '/dev/employee';**

I have orc data files inside these partitioned folder.

**hdfs dfs -ls /dev/employee**

drwxr-xr-x   - user1 group1        0 2017-02-08 10:25 /dev/employee/partition_upd_gmt_ts=201609
drwxr-xr-x   - user1 group1        0 2017-02-08 10:24 /dev/employee/partition_upd_gmt_ts=201610

When I execute this query

**select count(*) from dev.employee where 1=1;**

1000  -- correct rowcount

I have another table replica of employee table in prod schema.This is also a external partitioned ORC table.I want to push the same data into that table also.

**CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE prod.employee(
  empid string,
  empname string,
  update_gmt_ts timestamp)
  PARTITIONED BY (
  partition_upd_gmt_ts string)
  stored as orc
  location '/prod/employee';**

so I did a hdfs copy

**hdfs dfs -cp /dev/employee/* /prod/employee/**

Data got copied .

**hdfs dfs -ls /prod/employee**

drwxr-xr-x   - user1 group1        0 2017-02-08 10:25 /prod/employee/partition_upd_gmt_ts=201609
drwxr-xr-x   - user1 group1        0 2017-02-08 10:24 /prod/employee/partition_upd_gmt_ts=201610

But when I executed the count query , I got zero rows.

> Could you please help me why I am not getting the same 1000 as row
>   count.

**select count(*) from prod.employee where 1=1;**

0  -- wrong rowcount

Comment: You did not declare the PARTITION explicitly, so Hive is not aware of the `/partition_upd_gmt_ts=*` directories... Search for "MSCK REPAIR" command.

Comment: I did not get your point . In both the table i have explicitly defined the partition column.

Comment: Thanks  Samson Scharfrichter

Comment: As this is partitioned table new table doesn't know about data in folder, you need to explicitly register those partitions;
Use dev;
"MSCK REPAIR table table_name"